# How to run web applications using jersey in an easy way?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat, intellij-idea, jersey

I created a web application using Jersey through this maven code:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp \
                -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
                -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service-webapp -Dpackage=com.example \
                -DarchetypeVersion=2.4.1
```

And I am using Tomcat v7 as my Java server. When I finish writing some code, I use mvn's package command to generate a .war file, copy this file to the /webapps folder and then start tomcat to run my application and test it on browser. But I think I waste lots of time doing these things. So I want to ask if there is an easier way test my code on browsers. How do you guys run your web applications, especially Jersey app, on your server?

And I am using Intellij Idea, does it have some features that help me build and run Jersey apps, or other J2EE apps? how to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA you can create a Tomcat Run/Debug configuration. In that configuration you can specify "before launch" tasks/options, including running a maven goal. So by running the Tomcat configuration, IDEA will run the maven goal, deploy your code to Tomcat, start the tomcat server, and (if desired) open you web browser to a specified page.

JetBrains has a [Getting Started with Spring MVC, Hibernate and JSON](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Spring+MVC,+Hibernate+and+JSON) tutorial. What you want to do is very similar. The main difference is you will need to remove the default "make" option in the "Before Launch" section at the bottom of the run/debug configuration and instead have it run your maven task.

There is also the [Creating a simple Web application and deploying it to Tomcat](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_and_deploying_it_to_Tomcat) tutorial. It's a little older and some of the options on the run/debug dialog have changed. But at the core, its still valid. Combined with the above, you should be in good shape.

Finally take a look at the *Run/Debug Configuration: Tomcat* page in the help guide (also available in the online [webhelp](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-tomcat.html)).